# How to add Multiple Floating button in Stack Widget in Flutter

Tags: dart, widget, stack, flutter

In flutter one view over another view using [Stack Widget](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html). It's work fine. Now I need to added two floating button left and right side of bottom of screen. I added one button right side but I dnt know how to add floating button left side. Simple like below image.

[image]

Any help will appreciable

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can use the [`Align`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html) widget to position your [`FloatingActionButton`'s](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/FloatingActionButton-class.html) in the [`Stack`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html).

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
      child: FloatingActionButton(...),
    ),
    Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
      child: FloatingActionButton(...),
    ),
  ],
)
```

One button uses constant `Alignment.bottomLeft` for its `alignment` property and the other one respectively `Alignment.bottomRight`.

Comment: But my left alignment gets out of the screen?

Comment: @KevinRED Same here

Comment: I had to make sure to set "heroTag: null," for each floating action button, per this article: https://medium.com/@kaendagger/test-cef30fcb5c54.  Otherwise, you get a black screen.

Comment: To fix the "left alignment gets out of the screen" issue add `floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked` to Scaffold

Answer (score 48):

**You can also use something like this using location as centerDocked so that you don't get that weird left alignment.**

```dart
floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
floatingActionButton: Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: <Widget>[
      FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Icon(Icons.navigate_before),
      ),
      FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Icon(Icons.navigate_next),
      )
    ],
  ),
)
```

Comment: This suits my requirement. I need both buttons should be at center. So i have changed "mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center". 
Thanks

Comment: it is not clear what floatingActionButtonLocation and floatingActionButton are, neither where they fit in inside the Stack widget mentioned by the OP. Neither what the formatting is supposed to indicate.

Answer (score 16):

Don't forget to set "heroTag: null," for each floating action button. otherwise you'll get a black screen!

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
      child: FloatingActionButton(
                heroTag: null,
             ...),
    ),
    Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
      child: FloatingActionButton(
                heroTag: null,
             ...),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 9):

```
floatingActionButton: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:31),
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
          child: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: picker,
            child: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),),
        ),),

        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
          child: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: picker2,
          child: Icon(Icons.add_photo_alternate),),
        ),
      ],
    )
```

Comment: The formatting of this answer really needs to be tidied up.  Also please consider adding some commentary to describe your answer, particularly highlighting which parts resolve the described problem.

Answer (score 9):

```
  floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
  floatingActionButton: Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: 10.0),
    child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: <Widget>[
        FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: _someBackMethod,
          child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
        ),
        FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: _someForwardMethod,
          child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

[image]

Comment: thats the best answer! is it also possible to notch the buttons in a BottomAppBar?

Answer (score 7):

```dart
Scaffold(
  floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
  floatingActionButton: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 12),
    child: Row(
      children: [
        FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          child: Icon(Icons.remove),
        ),
        Spacer(),
        FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

just add **row**  as **floatingActionButton** in **Scafold** and set position **centerFloat**

as **EX**

```
Scaffold(
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
      //store btn
      floatingActionButton: Container(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            //add left Widget here with padding left
            Spacer(
              flex: 1,
            ),
            //add right Widget here with padding right
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply clever ;)

```
Stack(
  children: [
    Container(...),
    Positioned(
      right: 15,
      bottom: 15,
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        heroTag: 'edit',
        onPressed: () {},
          child: Icon(Icons.edit),
      ),
      ),
      Positioned(
      left: 15,
      bottom: 15,
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        heroTag: 'delete',
        onPressed: () {},
          child: Icon(Icons.delete),
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Comment: Please consider adding a description to the code so that we would understand WHY it solves the op's issue

Answer (score 1):

if this tree happen
There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree.

```
floatingActionButton: Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
   Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 70),
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
           child: FloatingActionButton.extended(
                  heroTag: "btn1",
                  // backgroundColor: Color(0XFF0D325E),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                  // child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
                  label: Text('Clear All Wifi'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    _sendMessage(all: 'Clear Wifi');
                  }),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
            child: FloatingActionButton(
                heroTag: "btn2",
                backgroundColor: Color(0XFF0D325E),
                child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
                onPressed: () {
                  _sendMessage(all: 'GETALLWIFI');
                }),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```