# How to add onPressed to each popup buttons in FloatingActionButton flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm a new flutter developer and I'm still learning.I am trying to use multiple FloatingActionButton to display different options for the user through which he can move to different pages. We have relied on choosing one of the options available in the FloatingActionButton button.
Now I have a ready example that displays the main FloatingActionButton button, and if the user presses it, it offers the user three different options.

I need to add onPressed to the three popup buttons. So I can add Navigator.push to the user using it.Please if someone knows the solution to help me with one of the pop-up buttons, how can I do that so that I can complete the following buttons.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => new MyHomePageState();
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;

  static const List<IconData> icons = const [
    Icons.sms,
    Icons.mail,
    Icons.phone
  ];

  static method1() {
    print('method 1');
  }

  static method2() {
    print('method 2');
  }

  static method3() {
    print('method 3');

  }

  List<Function> methods = [method1, method2, method3];

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = new AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    );
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Color backgroundColor = Theme.of(context).cardColor;
    Color foregroundColor = Theme.of(context).accentColor;
    return new Scaffold(

      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text('Speed Dial Example')),

      floatingActionButton: new Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: new List.generate(icons.length, (int index) {
          Widget child = new Container(
            height: 70.0,
            width: 56.0,
            alignment: FractionalOffset.topCenter,
            child: new ScaleTransition(
              scale: new CurvedAnimation(
                parent: _controller,
                curve: new Interval(0.0, 1.0 - index / icons.length / 2.0,
                    curve: Curves.easeOut),
              ),
              child: new FloatingActionButton(
                heroTag: null,
                backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
                mini: true,
                child: new Icon(icons[index], color: foregroundColor),
                onPressed: () {
                  methods[index]();
                },
              ),
            ),
          );
          return child;
        }).toList()
          ..add(
            new FloatingActionButton(
              heroTag: null,
              child: new AnimatedBuilder(
                animation: _controller,
                builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
                  return new Transform(
                    transform: new Matrix4.rotationZ(
                        _controller.value * 0.5 * math.pi),
                    alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                    child: new Icon(
                        _controller.isDismissed ? Icons.share : Icons.close),
                  );
                },
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                if (_controller.isDismissed) {
                  _controller.forward();
                } else {
                  _controller.reverse();
                }
              },
            ),

          ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50839282/how-to-add-multiple-floating-button-in-stack-widget-in-flutter) might help you solve your problem. Happy coding!

Comment: methods 1,2,3 are properly called when the respective buttons are pressed. SO onPressed is already implemented for them. Where exactly do you want your opPressed functionality ?

Comment: Yes, there are three buttons that pop up, but I do not know how I can make the user go through them to different pages @SarveshDalvi